# What's the best way to style an email template in Django?

Tags: html, css, django, email

I am trying to style an email template in Django. From researching the best way to do this seems to be to do inline CSS styles. This seems like it would be a tedious process so was wondering if anyone has any better suggestions?

I saw another suggestion saying to use django-inlinecss but I can't for the life of me locate the css file when using
{% inlinecss "static/css/email.css" %}

Path of template: Coronavirus_Dashboard/home/templates/home/newsletter_emails/newsletter_body.html
Path to CSS: Coronavirus_Dashboard/static/css/email.css

I just keep getting a file not found error, not sure what way I need to specify the location.

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the "static/" from the path. `inlinecss` starts in "static/" so you tell it to look in "static/static/css/email.css" in your code.

Source: [django-inlinecss readme](https://github.com/roverdotcom/django-inlinecss)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried it without static. I tried:
css/email.css
email.css

Answer (score 0):

Ah okay, I figured it out. I had set STATIC_ROOT to be staticfiles so I needed to run collect static for my css file to be added to staticfiles